# Program in C# to read a file:Button not working

Tags: c#, button

Here is my code, for some reason button two doesn't fire, button one does and when I place the code from button 2 into one it works there.  What am i missing about the syntax to get buttons one and two to both work on click?  I am about 2 weeks into learning c# so this is all new to me, I do not see why this code should not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string filePath = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Method to check database connection
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("button1.Click was raised.");
        }

        //Method to select a file
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = file.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned the click event to the button2_click method?

Comment: The code posted is incomplete, there is no sign of events being assigned. The program is using a `.designer.cs` file, which is not posted, and thus it is impossible for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the event handler isn't subscribed (anymore). So have a look at the partial class of `Form1` in the auto generated file `Form1.Designer.cs`. There must be somewhere this:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
// is this missing?
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
```

[How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to register all of those event handlers in their designer.cs files.  This is a really cool way to keep your code clean.  I am really liking c#

Comment: @ZachM.: Normally they are added automatically for example when you double-click on the button. But maybe you have renamed it. Note that you should not use the designer.cs to initialize your controls since it's an auto generated file. Your changes can be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `button2` is bound.

From the designer, select the button then go to the properties window. Click the lightning bolt, and make sure the click event is bound to `button2_Click`.

Alternative method is right-clicking on `InitializeComponent()` and select "Go to definition" (brings you to `Form1.designer.cs`) and look for the following:

```
button2.OnClick += new EventHandler(button2_Click);
```

If you've confirmed it's bound, we'll need to see more than what you've shown to determine the problem.